# Trying to update record in entity framework The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I been searching all day trying to find how to solve this problem I got. Still haven't found a solution.

I'm getting this error, when trying to update a record in my database using entity framework.

*The relationship could not be changed because one or more of the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.*

```
public bool PostChangesStudent(Student updatedStudent)
{
    // Get current student from the database.
    var student = _db.Students.Find(updatedStudent.Id);

    if (student != null)
    {   
        // Clear all cources from the ICollection list.   
        student.Courses.Clear();
        foreach (var course in updatedStudent.Courses)
        {
            // Adds the new edited courses
            student.Courses.Add(course);
        }

        // Save changes in database
        _db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;           
        _db.SaveChanges();
}
```

As the error describes, I delete the old courses object inside the Courses list, and then i guess a new relation should be added? I just can't figure out what to do next.

What you see is that I get the (non edited) object from the database (student), and the updatedStudent object i can retrieve using the parameter (updatedStudent).

**Student and Course model**

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string StudentNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; } 


    // Courses
    public virtual ICollection<Course> Courses{ get; set; }
}

public class Course
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string CourseName { get; set; }
    public int CourseNumber { get; set; }
}
```

**This is a One to many relationship,**

I have already set up test data using a Context class and a ContextInitializer, which I solved using this tutorial:

[Entity framework 6 tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

Have read alot of stack post of this problem, but can't understand what to do..

**Update**

Sorry I made a typo.. I'm using clear to take out the courses from the original student object i got from the database.

Then I loop over the updatedStudent.Courses which consist of edited courses and mapping them inside the student object.

When that is done, I want to save the object again in the database to it has the new courses (updated ones).

**Update2**

After discussions with danludwig, I finally got this to work :D

Here is what to do:

1. Remove clear like he said.
2. Clear courses from student object like this code:

   ```
   foreach (var course in student.Courses.ToArray())
   {
       _db.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Deleted;
       student.Courses.Remove(course);
   }
   ```
3. loop though updatedStudent.Courses and add course object to student object.

   ```
   foreach (var course in updatedStudent.Courses) 
   {
       student.Courses.add(course);
   }
   ```

Hope this can help other with this crazy error!

Comment: The problem is almost certainly in the `foreach` loop where you are trying to add `Course`s.  Have you debugged and stepped through the code to see what is happening?  I'm surprised it does anything at all.  First you clear the `Courses` collection, then you iterate through the `Courses` collection (which should be empty) and add each element back to `Courses`.  It makes very little sense.

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo.. it is the updatedStudent which i use the foreach around, and take those course and put them inside

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is likely coming from this line:

```
student.Courses.Clear();
```

...because `Course` has 2 non-nullable foreign key properties. When you clear these from the `Student`, you are "changing the relationship", and hence EF will try to set `Course.StudentId` to null. Which it can't. Because it's a non-nullable foreign key property.

Do you really mean to delete these courses? If so, delete them instead of removing them from the collection (or mark their state as deleted on the context).

```
// student.Courses.Clear(); get rid of this line, it is bad for you
foreach (var course in student.Courses.ToArray())
{
    _db.Entry(course).State = EntityState.Deleted;
    student.Courses.Remove(course);
}
```

> As the error describes, I delete the old courses object inside the Courses list...

No, you are not deleting anything anywhere. In EF, removing an item from a one-to-many collection property **is not the same as deleting it**. Even though you remove them from the `student.Courses` collection, the EF context is still tracking these entities and by default will just try to set their foreign key values to null. Which it can't. Because it's a non-nullable foreign key property.

Comment: No.. sorry, was a typo .. i am taken the courses from updatedStudent and putted them inside the student object. Have updated my post!

Comment: Huh? I still see this line in the OP: `student.Courses.Clear();`

Comment: @Mandersen I see your updates. What code comes immediately after the `// Clear all cources from the ICollection list` comment?

Comment: When debugging and using clear, it has count = 0 (which means 0 courses inside) , before clear it had 2 rows (count = 2). 

After the foreach, it has the same rows again with the same Id and foreign Id but with a different CourseNumber or name as an example.

Comment: @Mandersen yes I understand the code, and I am telling you that clearing the original 2 courses from the ICollection is what is causing this error, because EF is unable to set THEIR `Course.StudentId`'s to null.

Comment: Ok, I will remove clear and map from one object to the other (the important parts like Name, Number.

Comment: You are a life savior.. thanks so much man! works.. I have made an updated2 with what i did!